# Scene aligned pooling (SAP)

Tags: video, deep-learning, pooling

Scene aligned pooling (SAP)
I am working on deep learning for the first-person video
And I need help how to applicate scene aligned pooling(SAP)

Comment: This isn't really a site for requesting tutorials. Once you've got some code written and have a *specific* problem you're trying to solve (e.g. "Here's my code, and when I train it on this dataset, it seems to overfit heavily, even when I try this, this, and this. [image of training/validation error plot]"), we might be able to help you.

Comment: I ask that question because I couldn't find any source codes. Here is a link to the article ( http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/dvmm/publications/12/ECCV_Pooling.pdf )

Comment: @imem Have you tried contacting the authors and asking for their code? Or writing your own code? Page 9 of the paper has a description of the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I did contact the writer but unfortunately, the code is not open source.
I'm still students and I don't have enough experience in deep learning so I can write that code also I don't have enough time.

Comment: That's unfortunate. They really *should* share their code so their results can be reproduced, but if they refuse, there's not much we can do. And we don't have time to write the code for you, either. On the positive side, if you ever *do* find the time to write the code, and actually *release* your version, you can probably get a paper out of it, or at least an arxiv paper. It'd get cited, too, any time someone wants to do work with SAP and doesn't want to write the code. And if you went that route, we *would* be able to give feedback on any specific problems you have once you had some code.

Comment: The lack of experience isn't a permanent issue; the only way to get experience is to find things you lack the experience to do and try them anyway. Deep learning isn't that hard; the math isn't much worse than in traditional neural nets; they're just bigger now because we have giant GPUs that can do the necessary calculations quickly enough. You might try running through some of the tutorials at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials as a starting point.